# MYSQL database transfer using knex

Tags: mysql, node.js, knex.js

```
const exec_string = 'mysqldump --user=abc--password=abc--host=localhost test | mysql --user=xyz--password=xyz --host=localhost new_test';
knex.raw(exec_string)
.then((res) => {
    console.log("res >>",res);
})
.catch((err)=>{
    console.log("err >>",err);
})
```

Here i have test database. i want transfer that database in new_test database using knex npm.
If any other solution please suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

`Knex` is not the right tool for this. Using exec or shelljs sounds like a good way to do this.

Comment: `const exec_string = 'cd C:/xampp/mysql/bin mysqldump --user=abc--password=abc--host=localhost test | cd C:/xampp/mysql/bin mysql --user=abc--password=abc--host=localhost new_test';`
`exec(exec_string, function(error, stdout, stderr) {});`
When i execute this code faced this error **The system cannot find the path specified.** cd C:/xampp/mysql/bin path can successfully run in cmd .@Mikael Lepistö